# How to edit "Most Visited" section of new tab page in Chromium?

Tags: chromium

When I open a new tab in Chromium, it displays the 'new tab' page, which (among other things) contains the 'most visited' pages.  I want to add a new webpage to that list.  How do I do that?

I've tried visiting the webpage several times, and clicking the 'X' for the other choices, but it never shows up.  Is there a way to manually edit what pages show up there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Most Visited" section on new tab in Chrome/Chromium can be edited by hand, by directly changing "Top Sites" sqlite3 database inside Chrome/Chromium with `sqlite3` and SQL (or by any other sqlite3 db editor, like [`sqlitebrowser`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sqlitebrowser/)).

The "Top Sites" database is located in user profile directory, the default one is "`~/.config/chromium/Default/Top Sites`" (for chrome: `~/.config/google-chrome/default`, in windows `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`).

To edit it, close the Chromium/Chrome and run for GUI editor

```
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
sqlitebrowser ~/.config/chromium/Default/Top\ Sites
```

Open `thumbnails` table in `Browse Data` tab. We ([and forensics experts](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/01/21/google-chrome-forensics/)) can see much more entries than is shown in "Most Visited".

Only eight sites with smallest "`url rank`" and not blacklisted by user are shown. You can see them with such SQL query (via "Execute SQL" tab in sqlitebrowser or by using `sqlite3 ~/.config/chromium/Default/Top\ Sites` command line tool):

```
select url, url_rank, at_top from thumbnails order by url_rank;
```

Now you can edit the database, changing `url_rank`s to reorder sites (you should shift half of url_ranks, if you are inserting in middle). You can ever add new url, and change all url_ranks to move your new url into "Most Visited".

When user deleted the site from "Most Visited" section by clicking "`x`" button, the url is blacklisted in the JSON config file `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`, in `ntp.most_visited_blacklist` section (close the Chrome, open the Preferences with text editor like gedit or vim, search for `most_visited_blacklist` and see `URLHash`es of blacklisted sites, implemented as MD5 of url string). You can delete all urls from `most_visited_blacklist` section (make sure that you have backup of Preferences file)

PS Actual source code of "Most Visited" implementation in Chromium: [`chrome/browser/history/top_sites_database.cc` file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/0cc95261bb66edbc70c9a91cb2fcbaa19740d816/chrome/browser/history/top_sites_database.cc), line 438, `void TopSitesDatabase::GetPageThumbnails` function:

```
  "SELECT url, url_rank, title, thumbnail, redirects, "
  "boring_score, good_clipping, at_top, last_updated, load_completed, "
  "last_forced FROM thumbnails ORDER BY url_rank, last_forced"));

// Results are sorted by url_rank. For forced thumbnails with url_rank = -1,
// thumbnails are sorted by last_forced.
```

Descriptions of some table fields are here: [`chrome/common/thumbnail_score.h`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/0cc95261bb66edbc70c9a91cb2fcbaa19740d816/chrome/common/thumbnail_score.h)

Blacklisting implemented in [`chrome/browser/history/top_sites_impl.cc`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/0cc95261bb66edbc70c9a91cb2fcbaa19740d816/chrome/browser/history/top_sites_impl.cc), `TopSitesImpl::AddBlacklistedURL`, `TopSitesImpl::RemoveBlacklistedURL` (Hmm, [used only by test](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=RemoveBlacklistedURL&type=cs&sq=package%3achromium), but not accessible in UI some time after url was blacklisted?)

Comment: This method is from 2014 and may not work in some newer versions. According to some commenter: "Tried it accordingly, it didn't work at all and I doubt it will work in the future. Chrome is (sadly) always changing and what worked in 2014 just doesn't work in 2016 anymore."

Answer (score 6):

You can use Chromium extension called **[Speed Dials](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi)** instead.

**Speed Dial replaces the Chrome\Chromium's new tab page with your predefined visual bookmarks.**

> To add a web page, just click on the Speed Dial toolbar button and select "Add this page". from this menu you can also open the Speed dial page to access your visual bookmarks.
>   When you're on the Speed Dial page, you can use drag-n-drop to change the thumbnail position.
>   Speed Dial let you customize the page look and feel by a predefined themes. You can also set a background image.

[image]

**Note:** It doesn't show the apps section.So whenever you need to access them , you need to disable it.

---

**If you don't like Speed dials; there are some steps you can do to keep the websites that you want:**

1. Clear Browsing History (Tools--->Clear browsing History).
2. Go to a specific website you want to keep.
3. The website will appear now on the "most visited" section, click on the pin as in this picture:
   [image]

4.Repeat from step 2 for every website.

Comment: Not exactly what I'd asked, but accomplished what I was trying to do.  Thanks!

Comment: @David Oneill: Answer updated.And I hope they will improve this "most visited" section to speed dials like Opera for example.

Comment: Just saw your edit - yeah, that's exactly what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 4):

You can't - not without visiting that site enough to make it into one of your "Most Visited" sites.

*(Via [Google Chrome Help](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95451))*

Answer (score 0):

You could remove your browers history and then go back to the site you want to see and would'll see it but the old entry's will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this only works with Google chrome but first bookmark the site you want on that page. While on the home page click and drag the bookmark to any space, used or empty, the cursor changes to an + ,click here. Next time you open the browser your site should be there. You can also fix or delete these shortcuts in that homepage

Comment: This didn't work, although it was worthy trying.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think I used to have a version of chrome with a page similar offered by speed dials, but you can still see the apps page. However, using speed dials you cant get access to speed dials.

Comment: Can you edit this to improve its clarity, and fix typos? (I'm sure you didn't mean to say "using speed dials you can't get access to speed dials" but I'm not sure what you *did* mean to say.)